# SendGrid API: Update contact's primary email address

Tags: email, contacts, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I would like to update a contact's primary email address. I looked through Google and SO but couldn't find anything on this. The problem is that I have automations running, so I can't delete and add new contact, as this would reset the automations and the contact would start receiving the automation emails from the beginning. Any ideas?

I looked through Google and StackOverflow but couldn't find anything on this. This endpoint: https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact doesn't allow you to update a contact's primary email address